# Can the 'safe-global/safe-infrastructure' repository be used for production?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

1. Can the [Running our services locally](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/blob/main/docs/running_locally.md) be used for production? If so, how can we remove the port number 8080 from the URL (e.g. http://localhost:8080/)?
2. Why did you include the word 'locally' in the sentence? It seems that this setup method is intended only for local testing and may not be suitable for public deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, but each team must adjust it according to their own specific requirements. To remove the port number, you should update the docker compose file and make some adjustments such as implementing a reverse proxy with HTTPS.
2. Perhaps because the purpose of this repository is to illustrate how the stack functions as a whole.